# logic for update multiple rows in same mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have query 1 and query 2 to update the same table.

How do i optimize this to single query.

```
$query1 = "UPDATE user_permissions SET active= 0 WHERE user_id = $my_user_id AND page_id =5";
$query2 = "UPDATE user_permissions SET active= 0 WHERE user_id = $my_user_id AND page_id =6";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN`

Like this:

```
UPDATE user_permissions SET active= 0 WHERE user_id = $my_user_id AND page_id IN (5, 6)
```